# USB video grabber works with camera, not with VHS recorder

Tags: video, video-editor, video-recording, v4l, video4linux

I'm trying to get rid of all my old videotapes using a USB grabber (`Fushicai USBTV007 Video Grabber [EasyCAP]`). When I use VLC or Open Broadcaster Software I can get the video stream from `/dev/video2`.

With an old Hi8 camera (Hitachi VM-H630E) it works fine, but with my VHS player (Thomson VTH6210) it just gives a black screen and no sound. I know the player is fine because on a television it just works.

I've tried to change all settings I could find (using the *monkey testing* industry standard), but it makes no difference at all.

How can I get this working?

Comment: Maybe the VHS player is outputting an incompatible signal? Aren't you too young to be playing with VHS tapes?

Comment: Check the setup of the VHS player, as some that have multiple outputs, require that you select the desired video output ports... ie: composite vs component, etc.